# Php script simply not executing

Tags: php, arrays, image, for-loop

I'm having some problems with a php script that is supposed to put some generated images in different folders, and it's just simply not being executed. I get no response from running the script and it worked just fine for for some changes ago.

```
<?php
    echo "hej";
    $classarray = array("Lk10", "Lk11", "Lk12a", "Lk12b", "Mb10a", "Mb10b", "Mb11a", "Mb11b", "Mb12a", "Mb12b", "MbV12", "Mst10", "Mt10", "Mt12", "MtE11", "MtS11");
    foreach ($classarray as $value)
    {
        echo $value . "<br>";
        if (!mkdir($value))
        {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
    $ind = 0;
    for ($t = 0; $t < count($t); $t++)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        {
            $vecka = $i;
            $schemaadressarray = array("http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={FDCE3A18-B5F6-45F4-B9B2-EA9171290F71}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={9407F354-F253-4289-861B-F1F6A1C37932}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={630EE8B5-18EE-42FF-ABB1-0F58725208FE}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={1410A36C-2731-4F2A-A635-C705367A076C}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={1F546257-A731-4A50-BF1F-D6D43A360F73}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={408ADF22-E6A3-4DDD-AD16-476B41F91A3A}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={E5FA8180-F4BB-4405-9201-17E99BB566F4}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={30650758-86A5-4D31-8E06-8DF98B032964}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={27787EAA-583A-4D58-BA7F-61BF646C2231}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={A126BC26-7000-4580-826B-328A96E6B156}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={6A504AB9-F851-4EBF-A4AC-5720B4956FDD}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={F81C9984-4565-4F2B-9F7C-EBCD3805397A}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={F7785411-BF36-430F-ABF1-AE456D174CDB}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={76B2F681-AE2E-4754-9609-47672369D58C}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={0B676B2D-9158-4FB4-9702-9F30FD78432F}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874", "http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={1CF5E0E8-F7E9-4C1B-BA8E-3B6B1FA9AC28}&period=&week=" . $vecka . "&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1883&height=874&maxwidth=1883&maxheight=874");
            $path = $classarray[$currentIndex] . "/schema{$i}.png";
            file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($schemaadressarray[$t)));
        }
        $currentIndex++;
        $ind++;
    }
?>
```

I'd be really grateful if someone would be able to pinpoint the error that stops this script to execute!

Best Regards

FreeSirenety

Comment: What was the output you were getting when it worked? What is the output you are getting now?

Comment: There are suntax errors in this piece of code. Turn the error reporting on! And use IDE.

Comment: Start with adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`  to the top of the page. See if that gives you an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($schemaadressarray[$t]));
```

You were missing that **]** and had a **)** instead.

Edit:

This was the wrong part:

```
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($schemaadressarray[$t)));
```

Comment: that's not the only error here =) `$schemaadressarray` is defined incorrectly too

Comment: @k102 true but syntax wise that is correct :) logic wise wrong